# javafx 8 border collapse

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

I've a pretty basic problem with composing JavaFX 8 components that are next to each other and suppose to have borders. Is there any flag to indicate them to blend in one border?
[image]

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class SettingsList {

    private VBox root;

    private String[] settingsList = new String[]{"set1", "set2", "set3"};

    public SettingsList(){

    }

    public Parent getControl(){
        root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("settingList.css").toExternalForm());
        for(String settingName: settingsList){
            Label settingLabel = new Label(settingName);
            settingLabel.getStyleClass().add("setting-label");
            root.getChildren().add(settingLabel);
        }

        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you exactly mean by blend in one border? Where they touches each other you only want one border except of two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no baked-in equivalent of `border-collapse`. Treat the first one differently:

```
boolean first = true ; 
for(String settingName: settingsList){
    Label settingLabel = new Label(settingName);
    settingLabel.getStyleClass().add("setting-label");
    if (first) {
        settingLabel.getStyleClass().add("first");
    }
    first = false ;
    root.getChildren().add(settingLabel);
}
```

and then in the CSS

```
.setting-label {
    -fx-label-padding: 10 ;
    -fx-border-color: black ;
    -fx-border-width: 0 1 1 1 ;
}
.setting-label.first {
    -fx-border-width: 1 ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I've been doing until know and I've been wondering if there's any other option. Thanks!